# I have a question regarding use of loop diuretics in hypertension

Tags: diuretics, hypertension

I understand that loop diuretics decrease BP because they are inhibiting the NKCC2 co-transporter so that sodium would not get reabsorbed. But while you are inhibiting the co-transporter, it also causes less sodium passing through the macula densa and so leads to increase of renin secretion. While renin is causing increase of BP, then why are we using loop diuretics to lower the BP?? Aren't the effects contradicting?